# The URL/Endpoint Address of a running WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service (A) that runs in a web type container (IIS etc etc). I need to send the endpoint address/URL of this service (A) to another service (B). The service (A) is configured via web.config and the system.serviceModel tags. How can I find the endpoint address/URL of the service (A) in c#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked at `OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress`

[From MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.endpointdispatcher.endpointaddress.aspx):

> Gets the address of the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I have tested that this would work for me I'll mark this as the answer and uptick it ... Thanks :)